# Randomize a List of Elements in a Powershell Array

Tags: arrays, list, powershell, random

I'm looking to take an array of elements and return a randomized version of the array in a function.

For example:

```
function Randomize-List
{
   Param(
     [int[]]$InputList
   )
   ...code...
   return 10,7,2,6,5,3,1,9,8,4
}

$a = 1..10
Write-Output (Randomize-List -InputList $a)
10
7
2
...
```

You get the idea.  No idea of how to approach this, I'm new to Powershell, coming from a Python background.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `Get-Random` to do this in PowerShell.

```
function Randomize-List
{
   Param(
     [array]$InputList
   )

   return $InputList | Get-Random -Count $InputList.Count;
}

$a = 1..10
Write-Output (Randomize-List -InputList $a)
```

Comment: You could also use `$InputList | Sort-Object {Get-Random}` [[source](http://www.ilovepowershell.com/easiest-way-shuffle-array-powershell/)].

Comment: `Get-Random` proves to be much faster than `Sort-Object`, especially for large input arrays. See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75355009/7571258). Also, PowerShell Core 7+ adds `Get-Random` parameter `-Shuffle`, so we can write `$shuffledArray = Get-Random -InputObject $arrayToShuffle -Shuffle`