# Using System.Random in PowerShell to Retrieve a Random List from an Array

Tags: powershell, random

I need a list of generated six-digit numbers

First I generated a list of numbers.

```
$Numbers += 0..999999  | ForEach-Object {

    if ( ($_ -as [string]).Length -eq 1 ) {
        "00000$_"
    }elseif ( ($_ -as [string]).Length -eq 2 ) {
        "0000$_"
    }elseif ( ($_ -as [string]).Length -eq 3 ) {
        "000$_"
    }elseif ( ($_ -as [string]).Length -eq 4 ) {
        "00$_"
    }elseif ( ($_ -as [string]).Length -eq 5 ) {
        "0$_"
    }else{$_ -as [string]}
    
}
```

Next, I shuffle the list.

```
$RandomNumbers = $Numbers | Sort-Object { Get-Random }
```

And that's exactly what takes too long for me.

Is there a way to have the numbers sorted faster?

I thought about "System.Random", but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: BTW: Your code to create strings from numbers with leading zeros can be written much simpler like this: `0..999999 | ForEach-Object {'{0:d6}' -f $_ }` ;-)

Comment: How many random number do you need?  You are generating and sorting 1 million numbers which takes lots of times.  Only generate the minimum number of random numbers that you need.

Comment: @jdweng, I really need 1 million random numbers from 000001 to 999999

Comment: So you just need the numbers from 1 to 999999 in a random order.  You may elaborate a little more detailed what you're actually trying to do. There might be a better way. ;-)

Comment: Do you want one of each number, or can you have repeats? zett43 solution will give repeats.

Comment: @jdweng,  I need uniq numbers and his solution sorts only my arry that contains unique numbers.

Comment: Then you have to generate the numbers like you originally did.  The assign a random number to each of the number and finally shuffle the numbers by the random number.  there is no need to cast numbers to string.  You can do that later when you get the random numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Get-Random` not only to generate random numbers but also to efficiently **shuffle** a collection:

```sh
$RandomNumbers = Get-Random -InputObject $Numbers -Count $Numbers.Count
```

This takes less than a second on my machine for one million numbers, whereas your original code took 27 seconds.

As expected, the `$RandomNumbers` array only contains unique numbers, which I have verified using `($RandomNumbers | Sort-Object -unique).Count` which outputs `1000000`.

---

If you have **PowerShell 7+** available, you can slightly **simplify** the code by replacing the the `-Count` parameter with the [`-Shuffle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-random?view=powershell-7.3#-shuffle) parameter:

```sh
$RandomNumbers = Get-Random -InputObject $Numbers -Shuffle
```

Comment: Thanks for help.
Since I really need 1 million random numbers, your solution is exactly what I need. Now it takes only 700 miliseconds instead of 40 seconds

Comment: @uragus Glad to be helpful. There were two errors in the description (100k instead of 1M), which I just fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not that `Get-Random` is particularly slow, it's that you're generating way more data than necessary. As [jdweng comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75355009/using-system-random-in-powershell-to-retrieve-a-random-list-from-an-array/75355868#comment132965541_75355009):

> Only generate the minimum number of random numbers that you need.

If you only need 1000 numbers between 0 and 999999, call `Get-Random` only 1000 times:

```
$RandomNumbers = 1..1000 |ForEach-Object { 
  '{0:d6}' -f (Get-Random -Min 0 -Max 1000000)
}
```

---

If the numbers have to be *distinct*, you can use a `HashSet<int>` or a hashtable to keep track of unique values until you reach the desired amount:

```
$NumberCount = 1000

$newNumbers = @{}
while($newNumbers.psbase.Count -lt $NumberCount){
  $newNumbers[(Get-Random -Min 0 -Max 1000000)] = $true
}

$RandomNumbers = $newNumbers.psbase.Keys |ForEach-Object ToString d6
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I would keep it in mind